# Optimizing design with many identical units that could be shared

Tags: optimization, vhdl

I have a design that generates a video signal on demand, without using RAM resources for a framebuffer.

I have a hierarchy that represents the screen layout, with a toplevel block generating the pixel clock and sync signals, and creating a signal that shows the coordinates of the next pixel. Below that are various blocks with the same interface:

```
type point is record
    valid : std_logic;
    x : unsigned(11 downto 0);
    y : unsigned(11 downto 0);
end record;

type color is record
    r : std_logic;
    g : std_logic;
    b : std_logic;
end record;

component source is
    port(
        pos : in point;
        col : out color);
end component;
```

The general idea is that each of these blocks either generates a signal directly, or contains sub-blocks.

I'd like to stick with the pixel-on-demand schema, as it allows me to do

```
architecture syn of zoom2_block is
    signal slave_pos : point;
begin
    slave_pos.valid <= pos.valid;
    slave_pos.x <= "0" & pos.x(10 downto 1);
    slave_pos.y <= "0" & pos.y(10 downto 1);

    slave : source port map(
        pos => slave_pos,
        col => col);
end architecture;
```

Now, the innermost pixel generators for several blocks are fairly similar (e.g. font pixel lookup), and because only one pixel will ever be passed outside, I wonder whether I can somehow share blocks, e.g. like the `font` in the hierarchy

```
output
  source : split_screen
    source : zoom
      source : text
        font  
    source: text
      font
```

The `text` blocks themselves cannot be shared, because these contain the actual character codes given to the `font` blocks -- but the `font` block is twice exactly the same -- taking a coordinate and character code and returning the appropriate pixel value, with no state. Since the font data is large, not being able to share these is a problem.

Ideas I've had so far:

1. Have every block output `'-'` while `pos.valid = '0'`, in the hope that the compiler will notice that this will be the case only for one block in the hierarchy, at all time. I'm not sure the compiler will get this.
2. Create a special component that arbitrates access to the font block, as a generic with `array(1 to N) of point` interface, selecting the first input with `pos.valid = 1`. This would still require me to build a hierarchy that is no longer a tree.

Can this be done?

Comment: You're trying to put this in an FPGA, right? What hardware are you trying to create? If you separate your architecture too much from the actual hardware you want to exist, it won't be an efficient model. 

The optimizer will generally combine what LUTs can be combined (known as resource sharing). I'm not sure your brand of optimizer cares about "don't care" (`'-'`) these days, but I wouldn't rely on it.

Creating a block that "arbitrates" access to your font block is a good idea, as you can turn that into real hardware (a priority encoder and a mux).

Comment: The final design is a CNC machine controller that switches between different inputs (handwheel, parallel port for Mach3, Arduino with GRBL) and keeps a continuous position and status display. Over time, I'm probably going to add more features to it, so I want to keep it modular, and use a `configuration` to put it all together.

Comment: The main difficulty with arbitrating access is how to connect multiple blocks in a hierarchy to a single instance of a block somewhere else. The obvious answer would be adding a backplane bus that is routed to all components, but that is the opposite of modular.

Comment: By hardware, I meant imagine how your logic can be mapped into LUTs and FFs, the basic building blocks within an FPGA.

Comment: If you are seeking modularity, the typical way to achieve most of that is through the use of generics. It is fairly simple create a priority encoder+mux structure that will expand to fit a generic number of inputs. For components that have the same interface, you can use varying architectures for the same entity, but generics and generates are usually more flexible.

Comment: Ideally, it would generate a blob that implements the font data lookup, and a blob that maps the input coordinates to font coordinates. In the code, that is represented by multiple entities, but logically, it is `if x >= 100 and x < 200 and y >= 100 and y < 200 then font_x := x - 100; font_y := y - 100; elsif x >= 200 and x < 300 and ...`.

Comment: So the goal is to represent this `if ... elsif ... elsif ... else` structure as entities, so they can be plugged together with `configuration`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126638/discussion-between-quantumripple-and-simon-richter).